# Retrieve entire HTML with urlopen(url)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriver, urllib

I have noticed if I request a url using

```
urllib.request.urlopen([my_url]).read()
```

I get something like this:

```
 <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <span>...</span>
<body>
<script>
</script>


</html>
```

All the info I want for beautifulsoup is in that `<span>...</span>` section.  If I use a webdriver, then that section is included.  But a webdriver seems to take longer, and causes my code to be a bit more messy.  Is there way to retrieve the entirety of the HTML doc without using a webdriver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a much simpler and easy to read solution to parse the contents of the **`<span>`** tag :

```
import bs4
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

my_url = 'https://www.foo.com'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
span_content = page_soup.findAll("span",{"<attribute_name>":"<attribute_value>"})
print(span_content.text)
```

Comment: This still only gives me <span>...</span>.  If I add an attribute my findAll list is [ ]. The wedDriver seems to be the only way I can find to gather all the contents in the html.  If you'd like to see an example of the different methods, I've added the script here: https://github.com/mws75/UserName_by_Tag/blob/master/HashTag_SE_Test.py

Comment: Hello DebanjanB, I apologize, I didn't have time to test this till now, but your method works great.  It's fast, and gets the info I need.  I haven't figured out how to load more of the page though, so that's my next step.  But if I can figure that out, my webscraper will be much faster than using Selenium.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the famous request library, see if the below code will help you

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.google.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

span = soup.find_all('span')
print(span)
```

Comment: I'm still only getting <span>...</span>.  Feel free to test the different methods.  I've posted the code here: https://github.com/mws75/UserName_by_Tag/blob/master/HashTag_SE_Test.py